# Using go-websocket behind Apache mod_proxy_wstunnel

Tags: apache, websocket, go, mod-proxy

*Note: Updated config and added trailing slash to websocket path. Still same problem*

Is it possible to use [go-websocket](https://github.com/garyburd/go-websocket) behind a Apache reverse proxy with [mod_proxy_wstunnel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html)?

I tried and failed to get things working.

I tried to use [the Chat example](https://github.com/garyburd/go-websocket/tree/master/examples/chat) behind an Apache reverse proxy (with [mod_proxy_wstunnel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) enabled). And it doesn't work. The proxy is a success, while the websocket part does not work at all.

My Apache config looks similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foobar
    ServerName foobar.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPass /ws/ ws://localhost:8080/ws/
    ProxyPassReverse /ws/ ws://localhost:8080/ws/
    ErrorLog logs/error_log-foobar
    CustomLog logs/access_log-foobar common
    LogLevel debug
</VirtualHost>
```

And of course I'm running the chat server on port 8080. I've tested it with SSH tunnel, and things work perfectly. Then I moved on to Apache.

The first time I tried, the javascript console complains this:

```
NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://foobar.com/ws/
```

The request seems to be stucked at the origin check.
Then I tried again after comment out the origin check, it get this:

```
NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://foobar.com/ws/
```

It seems the chat server do not get the upgrade request at all.

How should I debug this?
Where should I start looking?

Comment: Does the trailing slash `/` matter? Just a guess....

Comment: No. I think not. I've just tried to add trailing slash to everything. The problem is still the same.

Comment: I imagine both servers have logging, what do they say?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass says that `ProxyPass` directives are matched in order, so your `/ws/` one is probably shadowed by `/` one.  Do you get a different behaviour if you change the order?

Comment: Thanks! The order does matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using Go secure WebSocket (wss://) server behind Apache 2.4.18 on CentOS 7. Here are the settings:

**Make sure the system has mod_proxy_wstunnel:**

# find /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/ | grep ws

```
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

**Add the following line in 00-proxy.conf:**

# vim /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf

```
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

**Restart Apache:**

# systemctl restart httpd

**Check the setting:**

# httpd -M | grep -iE 'proxy'

```
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
```

**Edit httpd-vhosts.conf:**

# vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName go.mydomain.com:443

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off

    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.com/mydomain.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/mydomain.com/mydomain.key"

    ### The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch rules are checked
    ### in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins.
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(ws(/.*)?)$ wss://192.168.0.1:443/$1

    ProxyPass / https://192.168.0.1:443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.0.1:443/

    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/go.mydomain.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/go.mydomain.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName go.mydomain.com:80

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests off

    ###
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(ws(/.*)?)$ ws://192.168.0.1:80/$1

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.1:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.1:80/

    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/go.mydomain.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/go.mydomain.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This answer was useful to me because i had to reverse proxy wss and https request without any /path/ to distinguish them. The ProxyPassMatch came in handy.

Answer (score 19):

Thanks everyone! After taking several advices above, I found the solution.

And for someone who might have similar issue, here is the solution to my question:

1. As [Aralo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/684167/aralo) suggested, trailing slash must be added to the WebSocket path (in my case: "/ws/"). It looks Apache will only handle WebSocket with a valid GET request.
2. [James Henstridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721283/james-henstridge) was right. The order of ProxyPass relevant. ProxyPass of /ws/ must be put before the / line.
3. After consulting the Chat example code, I found [an origin check](https://github.com/garyburd/go-websocket/blob/master/examples/chat/conn.go#L97) in the function [**ServeWs()**](https://github.com/garyburd/go-websocket/blob/master/examples/chat/conn.go#L92) and removed.

Everything works now.

And thanks [covener](https://stackoverflow.com/users/98959/covener), reading logs does help.

Comment: Can you post your final solution. Your questions has all of the things you mentioned in your answer. So, Im a little confused.

Comment: That was the full description of my final solution. Do you want me to post the actual configurations here? Or which part do you find hard to follow?

Comment: @KoalaYeung can you post your apache conf as well please.

Comment: We need to see which file at which path you have edited and how its looking finally so that we can compare our files with yours. Please post it ASAP as i already wasted 2 days while searching the solution.

Comment: Its great that you solve yourself. Could you please provide source code for this ... my email is veshraj.joshi1@gmail.com