# Preserve protocol in httpd proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, mod-proxy

I need to configure in Apache 2.4.9 (with mod_proxy and mod_proxy_wstunnel activated) a proxy with this mapping:

- http://my.proxy/*  -->  http://my.backend:8080/*
- ws://my.proxy/*    -->  ws://my.backend:8080/*

E.g.:

- ws://my.proxy/cometd-demo-2.8.0/cometd --> ws://my.backend:8080/cometd-demo-2.8.0/cometd
- http://my.proxy/cometd-demo-2.8.0/cometd --> http://my.backend:8080/cometd-demo-2.8.0/cometd
- http://my.proxy/cometd-demo-2.8.0/jquery-examples/chat/ --> http://my.backend:8080/cometd-demo-2.8.0/jquery-examples/chat/

In other words, I need a proxy that keeps (preserves) the protocol.

This configuration does not work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ...
   ProxyRequests Off
   ProxyPreserveHost Off
   ProxyPass / http://my.backend:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://my.backend:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

because all request (no matter protocol) are proxied to http*

Anyone knows how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784658/using-go-websocket-behind-apache-mod-proxy-wstunnel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A posible solution is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =WebSocket [NC,NV]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) ws://my.backend:8080/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://my.backend:8080/$1 [P]
```

Source: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-dev/201405.mbox/%3C6FF4EBA7-866D-4D76-A10D-3D04B896EE87@jaguNET.com%3E

Comment: Hi - can you please edit the essential parts of that into your answer so that it stands alone? Thanks!